# HDFS migrate datanodes servers to new servers

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I want to migrate our hadoop server with all the data and components to new servers (newer version of redhat).

I saw a post on cloudera site about how to move the namenode,
but I dont know how to move all the datanodes without data loss.
We have replica factor 2.
If I will shutdown 1 datanode at a time hdsfs will generate new replicas?
Is there A way to migrate all the datanodes at once? what is the correct way to transfer all (about 20 server) datanodes to a new cluster?

Also I wanted to know if hbase will have the same problem or if I can just to delete and add the roles on the new servers

Update for clearify:

My Hadoop cluster already contains two sets of servers (They are in the same hadoop cluster, I just splited it logicly for the example)

1. First set is the older version of linux servers
2. Second set is the newer version of linux servers

Both sets are already share data and components (the namenode is in the old set of servers).
I want to remove all the old set of servers so only the new set of servers will remain in the hadoop cluster.

Does the execution should be like:

1. shutdown one datanode (from old servers set)
2. run balancer and wait for finish
3. do the same for the next datanodes

because if so, the balancer operation takes a lot of time and the whole operation will take a lot of time.

Same problem is for the hbase, 
Now hbase region and master are only on the old set of servers, and I want remove it and install on the new set of servers without data loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

New Datanodes can be freely added without touching the namenode. But you definitely shouldn't shut down more than one at a time.

As an example, if you pick two servers to shut down at random, and both hold a block of a file, there's no chance of it replicating somewhere else. Therefore, upgrade one at a time if you're reusing the same hardware.

In an ideal scenario, your OS disk is separated from the HDFS disks. In which case, you can unmount them, upgrade the OS, reinstall HDFS service, remount the disks, and everything will work as previously. If that isn't how you have the server set up, you should do that before your next upgrade.

In order to get replicas added to any new datanodes, you'll need to either 1) Increase the replication factor or 2) run the HDFS rebalancer to ensure that the replicas are shuffled across the cluster

I'm not too familiar with Hbase, but I know you'll need to flush the regionservers before you install and migrate that service to other servers. But if you flush the majority of them without rebalancing the regions, you'll have one server that holds all the data. I'm sure the master server has similar caveats, although `hbase backup` seems to be a command worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I added an update to clearify my case.
Running the balancer for each shutdown will take to long.
And since im not upgrading the os I cant use the second option
Is there any other solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by new servers, then. Why do you need to replace the old ones completely? If theyre better hardware, you're more than doubling the storage and compute power, so keep them. Anyway, don't need to run the rebalancer one at a time, but you're risking data loss if more than one datanode is down. That's why you shouldn't have used a replication factor of 2

Comment: They are servers in the cloud so I have to dispose the old ones in order to keep the new servers (old are 6.3 redhat, new are 7.1 redhat) because of our system team demmand.
Also I cant upgrade the old servers to a newer version, I have to get the new servers and than remove the old servers.

Comment: Alright, well, I know both the namenode and hbase masters offer backup commands. And you can backup/snapshot hbase tables. If your hdfs data volumes are not detachable volumes, then you can still manually copy the datanode locations to the other servers (while the datanode service is stopped), however, I don't know how the namenode will know how the file pointers changed

Answer (score 0):

@guylot - After adding the new nodes and running the balancer process take the old nodes out of the cluster by going through the decommissioning process. The decommissioning process will move the data to another node in your cluster. As a matter of precaution, only run against on one node at a time. This will limit the potential for a lost data incident.